# my image did not placed as a full background img in html page

Tags: html, css, web

**this the code that i have written and it didn't work , my problem here is that code work but the image did not appear as it supposed to**

```
 .about-bg{  
   background: url(../img/about.jpg) no-repeat top center fixed !important;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
   background-position: top center;

   }
```

this isn't go well

[this the result that i had](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JLaZ.png)

Comment: You need to provide more information about what _is_ happening. There isn't enough information here to help.

Comment: What does this: _**did not appear as it supposed to**_ mean?

Comment: like what information ?

Comment: @Randy  it appear in center of screen but not full bg-screen

Comment: Provide some MINIMAL html please.

Comment: @RandyCasburn i had provide the result that i had

Comment: @Abdel-Elrahman - If my answer was acceptable, please consider accepting it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can't tell from your question, but you must ensure body margins and padding are both set to zero if you want any element on the page to cover the entire page.

If this element is contained within another element, that element must allow the image of expand beyond its borders or that element must be full-sized too.

Here is an example that sets a solid blue picture as the background image within a `div`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.about-bg {
  background: url(http://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/808080) no-repeat top center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="about-bg">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the question I presume you want the image to take up the entire background. I tried your code on a few pictures it seems it is because the picture dimensions don't match the screen so try this code ans see if it helps.

```css
.about-bg {
  margin:0;
   background: url(backpic.png) no-repeat;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   overflow:hidden;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing !important. It should let you take 100% of width